# explain based on the knowledge of hardware why "Certain floating-point values cannot be exactly represented inside the computer’s memory"?

Tags: objective-c, computer-science

> In the second line of the program’s output, notice that the value of
>   331.79, which is assigned to floatingVar, is actually displayed as 331.790009.The reason for this inaccuracy is the particular way in which numbers are internally represented inside the computer.You
>   have probably come across the same type of inaccuracy when dealing
>   with numbers on your calculator. If you divide 1 by 3 on your
>   calculator, you get the result .33333333, with perhaps some additional
>   3s tacked on at the end.The string of 3s is the calculator’s
>   approximation to one third.Theoretically, there should be an infinite
>   number of 3s. But the calculator can hold only so many digits, thus
>   the inherent inaccuracy of the machine.The same type of inaccuracy
>   applies here: Certain floatingpoint values cannot be exactly
>   represented inside the computer’s memory.

the above quote comes from *Programming in Objective-C – 4th edition*

And [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20341529/why-the-float-point-value-is-this) answered a little part but not the kind of answer i'm trying to look for.

Will try to find another book about this later in the day.

Anyway if anyone would like to answer this question, thanks!

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point

Comment: The root cause of the issue is not so much about hardware but about number theory (which I studied way back in the day...). We humans express numbers in base 10, which has prime divisors 2 and 5. Thus, fractions like 1/10 and 2/25 have representations in base 10 with a finite number of decimal digits. Fractions with other prime-divisor components, like 3/7, can be expressed concisely in base 7 but not in base 10. In binary, fractions with prime factors other than 2 in the numerator or denominator cannot be expressed in a finite number of digits.